# how to translate a java constraint into drools language

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

```java
Constraint roomConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    // A room can accommodate at most one lesson at the same time.
    return constraintFactory
            // Select each pair of 2 different lessons ...
            .forEachUniquePair(Lesson.class,
                    // ... in the same timeslot ...
                    Joiners.equal(Lesson::getTimeslot),
                    // ... in the same room ...
                    Joiners.equal(Lesson::getRoom))
            // ... and penalize each pair with a hard weight.
            .penalize("Room conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
}
```

Comment: Also, why would you want to go from Java to DRL? We generally see people going the other way. I am curious as to what your reasoning is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automated translation available; the constraint just has to be re-implemented in the Drools language.

For this particular constraint, it would be something along these lines:

```
rule "room conflict"
    when
        Lesson($id : id, $timeslot : timeslot, $room : room)
        Lesson(id > $id, timeslot == $timeslot, room == $room)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1);
end
```

It's actually similar to the original constraint definition: we penalize every pair of two distinct lessons that take place in the same room and at the same timeslot.

Comment: `Constraint teacherTimeEfficiency(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory){
 // A teacher prefers to teach sequential lessons and dislikes gaps between lessons.
return constraintFactory.forEach(Lesson.class).join(Lesson.class,Joiners.equal(Lesson::getTeacher),
Joiners.equal((lesson)->lesson.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek())).filter((lesson1,lesson2)->{ Duration between= Duration.between(lesson1.getTimeslot().getEndTime(),lesson2.getTimeslot().getStartTime());
return !between.isNegative() && between.compareTo(Duration.ofMinutes(30))<=0; }).reward("Teacher time efficiency",HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT);}`